# How to search for a newline that is not preceeded by } and remove it

Tags: sed, files, string, search, replace

I want to use `sed` to search for line breaks that are not preceded by `}`. 
The regex for identifying theses cases is: `[^}]$` . What I want to say: If the line ended without `}` then  remove the new line. Any line should end with `}` before the newline.

How to put that in `sed` to remove them?

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
{'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 07:23:14 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Vary': 'Qualys-Scan', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload', 'Set-Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=ivoa5bhet0s2ygkylmimvkie; path=/; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=strict, SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=12f133ea5080403692b4ce458fd1a540; expires=Thu, 19-Apr-2029 07:23:14 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=strict, SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE=336B597E7A534D6393C57DF11E047484|1|ivoa5bhet0s2ygkylmimvkie; path=/; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=strict, incap_ses_885_270026=cDp/VlO1AHgshF9F6SZIDGJ3uVwAAAAAg7DwpecyehBCyhXgoYO5GA==; path=/; Domain=.zurich.co.uk, ___utmvmykuNyVY=dlNaoEsuXSO; path=/; Max-Age=900, ___utmvaykuNyVY=nWJx01KvGT; path=/; Max-Age=900, ___utmvbykuNyVY=JZy
    XEtOwalQ: PtR; path=/; Max-Age=900', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=10', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'X-Iinfo': '8-3925806-3925807 NNNN CT(73 151 0) RT(1555658593583 5) q(0 0 3 0) r(6 6) U5', 'X-CDN': 'Incapsula', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
```

When I applied your script, it combined the lines. However, the new line starts with `tab`. How to also remove the spaces if the newline starts with spaces?

Comment: So if a line does not end with `}`, you want to *join* the next line to it?

Comment: yes. just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to join lines where the preceding line does not end with `}`:

```
sed -e :a -e '/}$/!N; s/\n//; ta'
```

This is essentially a variant of **39. Append a line to the next if it ends with a backslash "\"** from [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one), replacing the "ends with a backslash" condition with "does not end with a right brace".

Ex. given

```
$ cat > input
foo bar
baz}
foo bar baz}
```

then

```
$ sed -e :a -e '/}$/!N; s/\n//; ta' input
foo barbaz}
foo bar baz}
```

---

If you want to also remove any leading horizontal whitespace at the start of the joined line, you can change `s/\n//` to `s/\n[[:blank:]]*//`

Testing with your example (after converting the leading spaces to tabs):

```
$ cat example
        {'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 07:23:14 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Vary': 'Qualys-Scan', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload', 'Set-Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=ivoa5bhet0s2ygkylmimvkie; path=/; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=strict, SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=12f133ea5080403692b4ce458fd1a540; expires=Thu, 19-Apr-2029 07:23:14 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=strict, SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE=336B597E7A534D6393C57DF11E047484|1|ivoa5bhet0s2ygkylmimvkie; path=/; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=strict, incap_ses_885_270026=cDp/VlO1AHgshF9F6SZIDGJ3uVwAAAAAg7DwpecyehBCyhXgoYO5GA==; path=/; Domain=.zurich.co.uk, ___utmvmykuNyVY=dlNaoEsuXSO; path=/; Max-Age=900, ___utmvaykuNyVY=nWJx01KvGT; path=/; Max-Age=900, ___utmvbykuNyVY=JZy
        XEtOwalQ: PtR; path=/; Max-Age=900', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=10', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'X-Iinfo': '8-3925806-3925807 NNNN CT(73 151 0) RT(1555658593583 5) q(0 0 3 0) r(6 6) U5', 'X-CDN': 'Incapsula', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}

$ sed -e :a -e '/}$/!N; s/\n[[:blank:]]*//; ta' example
        {'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 07:23:14 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Vary': 'Qualys-Scan', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload', 'Set-Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=ivoa5bhet0s2ygkylmimvkie; path=/; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=strict, SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=12f133ea5080403692b4ce458fd1a540; expires=Thu, 19-Apr-2029 07:23:14 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=strict, SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE=336B597E7A534D6393C57DF11E047484|1|ivoa5bhet0s2ygkylmimvkie; path=/; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=strict, incap_ses_885_270026=cDp/VlO1AHgshF9F6SZIDGJ3uVwAAAAAg7DwpecyehBCyhXgoYO5GA==; path=/; Domain=.zurich.co.uk, ___utmvmykuNyVY=dlNaoEsuXSO; path=/; Max-Age=900, ___utmvaykuNyVY=nWJx01KvGT; path=/; Max-Age=900, ___utmvbykuNyVY=JZyXEtOwalQ: PtR; path=/; Max-Age=900', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=10', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'X-Iinfo': '8-3925806-3925807 NNNN CT(73 151 0) RT(1555658593583 5) q(0 0 3 0) r(6 6) U5', 'X-CDN': 'Incapsula', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
```

Comment: Can you explain the command with details? I do not get most of it.  What does `:a` is for? and the rest etc. It is complex

Comment: @None did you read the explanation in the provided link? I don't think I can do better than that

Comment: when I used your script, the first line that ends with `utmvbykuNyVY=JZy` converted to:  `utmvaykuNyVY=nW\` (the JZy replaced with nW\. Also the empty spaces at the beginning of the new line needs to be removed. Sorry I am not very familiar with Linux.

Comment: @None you can scoop up arbitrary horizontal whitespace by changing `s/\n//` to `s/\n[[:blank:]]*//`

Comment: Your command does not work with me. Can you plz check my edit in the post?

Comment: It changes the line content

Comment: the first line that ends with utmvbykuNyVY=JZy converted to: `utmvaykuNyVY=nW` (the JZy replaced with nW\)